# how to download multiple images from firestore storage in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-storage

For web.
Hey is there any possible to download url of files from firestore storage without providing the file name in the storage reference ? 
Like if we have to download and display all the images from a particular folder, is it must to know the names of all the files uploaded in that folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a download URL for a file, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), you will have to know the full path of the file.  There are no wildcards or folder links.